# Attaching rigid bodies in Motionbuilder 2014

Tags: markers, fbx, rigid-bodies

I have some optimal marker data imported from a C3D file in MotionBuilder. This marker data represents an animation of two feet of a character. Is there a way to attach rigid bodies to these markers and export the animation of the rigid body out to a fbx file ?

Just to clarify, I only have marker data for the feet and not the entire character.

Many thanks !

Cheers,
darkZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question :

1) Create a primitive from the Asset Browser in the Resources Pane by expaning the Elements subsection under the Templates section. Drag a cube to the scene.

2) Go to constraints under the Templates section and drag the Rigid body constraint to the scene.

3) Specify the constrained object for the Constraint to be this newly created cube. And keep adding all the desired markers which you want to drive this cube to the Sources in the Constraint Settings.

4) Repeat for all the required rigid bodies.

5) Send the scene to Maya etc. and export/edit rigid body animation as desired.